# Swift how to detect if the UITextView link has been clicked or another part of the UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UITextView that I have added a GestureRecognizer to. I have also turned on links for the UITextView.  With both tap events only the UITextView touch is run (clicking the link no longer opens up maps for example).  I want the behaviour to be do the link touch otherwise if they didn't touch a link run my GestureRecognizer.  How do I do this?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Let me understand better... you have one gesture Recognize for 2 views? Isn't better 2 gestures with the same selector instead?

Comment: Did you enable your gesture recognizer to be able to simultaneously recognized with other recognizers? Anyway if you do this you will probably get the link functionality back. But now both events will happen (link and your custom tap). You will probably need to cancel your gesture event on link-press. Maybe a flag or by chance it might be enough to just disable and reenable it instantly.

Comment: Thanks Matic.  You are correct enable both to fire is what I need to do.  I just need to know which event to hook into to disable either the link click event from firing or the other one.

Comment: Check which one fires first. If recognizer is first then set a timer to fire your event and cancel the timer on link-press event. If link-press event is first then either temporary disable the gesture recognizer or create a boolean property like `ignoreNextGestureEvent` and set it to `true`. Then on event if `true` set it to `false` and `return`.

Answer (score -2):

You must have `selectable == true` for the `UITextView` to recognize taps on links. Also you must return `true` from the `textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction)` delegate call to actually open the link. It's also a good idea to become a delegate of your gesture recognizer and return true from `gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)`.

Otherwise there should be no interference between gesture recognizers installed on the text view: if you tap a link it will open; tapping elsewhere fires the gesture recognizer (in case of a tap recognizer).

Comment: Hey Tamas. Both Gestures are recognized (link and tap).  The link only fires if clicking on a link but the tap also fires.  Clicking on a textview without a link does not cause the link event to fire.  Need to identify a way in the tap gesture that the user has clicked on a link.